# Use inherticed functions from a class in functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My current enterprise code has the concept of Base classes and Function Specific components

```
class Engine extends Component {
   render(){
       this.renderEngine();
   }
}
```

And then we have specific classes such as PetrolEngine and DieselEngine

```
class PetrolEngine extends Engine {
      makeLessSound(){
        console.log('Silence');
      }
      consumeMoreFuel(){
         console.log('Gobble up!')
      }
      renderEngine(){
        this.makeLessSound();
        this.consumeMoreFuel()
      }
 }
class DieselEngine extends Engine {
      makeMoreSound(){
        console.log('Grrr!');
      }
      consumeLessFuel(){
         console.log('Dieting!')
      }
      renderEngine(){
        this.makeMoreSound();
        this.consumeLessFuel()
      }
 }
```

Now I want to create a new component like `ElectricEngine`. Is there a way to write this as a functional component without affecting the existing class based components.

And yes I am aware that Composition should have been the better approach instead of inheritance here. But it is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible as classes are just a syntactical sugar over existing prototype-based inheritance.

```js
class Engine extends React.Component {
  renderEngine = () => {
    return null;
  };
  render() {
    return this.renderEngine();
  }
}

function ElectricEngine() {}
ElectricEngine.prototype = new Engine();
ElectricEngine.prototype.constructor = Engine;
ElectricEngine.prototype.makeLessSound = function() {
  return <p>Making less sound!</p>;
};
ElectricEngine.prototype.consumeMoreFuel = function() {
  return <p>Consuming less fuel</p>;
};
ElectricEngine.prototype.renderEngine = function() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>ElectricEngine</h3>
      {this.makeLessSound()}
      {this.consumeMoreFuel()}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <ElectricEngine />,
  document.getElementById("app")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

`ElectricEngine.prototype = Object.create(Engine.prototype)` is equivalent to `ElectricEngine extends Engine` and `ElectricEngine.prototype.render` will allow you to override the `render` method of the `Engine` component so that you can render `ElectricEngine`-specific JSX.

However, this doesn't really feel right and it doesn't look too good, and as you said, composition would be a better approach here.

I'd probably just stick to `class-based components` if you want to extend some functionality from parent components as it's much easier to work with them in your specific case.

Comment: Actually, I want my Base class to invoke the superclass.
hence Engine class should have a render method inside it. 
All other classes should have the renderEngine method which will be specific to every class that extends Engine. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @VarunG have a look at the edited code snippet. Also, a `superclass` is a class that has been extended by another class, so it is a `base class`.